# iOS push ARSCNView to UINavigationController and return from it

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, arkit

I have an iOS App with an UICollectionView as the main view controller with a UINavigationController. I then push an ARSCNView upon user request. It works as expected. When I hit the "return" button in the navigation controller the app returns to the collection view the app displays the collection view, but hangs and does not accept user input any more.

How do I correctly handle this situation? Right now I'm doing this:

```
let view = ARViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
```

but as mentioned above this causes the app to hang upon return.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you already have this in your code or if it will help, but are you pausing the ARKitSession on your ARKitSceneView in your viewWillDisappearMethod like so?

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Pause the view's AR session.
    sceneView.session.pause()
}
```

If you were to do this then you should also move your ARKitScene setup code to the viewWillAppear method of your View Controller as well. Unfortunately I don't have access to a Mac to test this but I thought I would give this as a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I already tried that and it did not help